# Highlighting specific countries (Ethiopia, Uganda, Kenya) using rworldmap library and map function

Tags: r, maps, rworldmap

I am using this code using the package **mapdata**, however it only show the three countries I have selected, and I cannot see the rest of the world´s map boundaries.

```
map("world", 
    regions=c("ethiopia", "kenya", "uganda"), 
    exact = TRUE, 
    fill=TRUE, 
    col=c(1,2,3))
```

How can I show the rest of the world's map boundaries while highlighting my three selected countries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example without rworldmap:

```
require(mapdata)

# get the names
cc <- map('world', names = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
take <- unlist(sapply(c("ethiopia", "kenya", "uganda"), grep, tolower(cc), value = TRUE))

# world
map()
# add the selected countries in grey to the plot
map('world', regions=take, fill=TRUE, col='grey50', add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I'd use a `bor = "red"`or similar, to highlight the selected countries a little more.

Comment: Thank you very much Simon. Just what I wanted! Perfect!